# WinSCP alternative with theme support?

Tags: windows, dark-theme, scp

I'm wondering if anybody knows of an alternative to WinSCP (I use it all the time), that supports theming (or at least a "dark" theme, similar to chromes inspector dark theme).  Its literally the only app I use that DOESN'T support theming and its driving me nuts.

Also, MUST be for Windows, preferably not cygwin based.

Any suggestions/aternative are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If integrating into Windows Explorer would work for you (I assume you have it set with a dark theme to your satisfaction already?) then check out Swish - https://www.howtogeek.com/165893/how-to-integrate-a-remote-sftp-directory-into-windows-explorer/

Comment: Sadly I'm still running Windows 7 which has very limited "dark" theme. However Swish is definitely a very cool idea. Never seen that before. Will try.

Answer (score 2):

WinSCP supports dark theme since 5.14.2:

[image]

You can enable dark theme in [Preferences on Interface page](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_interface#theme).